# Validation in Yii Framework

Tags: php, validation, yii, notifications

How to dynamically set border to fieldset in yii framework during validation?

On failure the border of fieldset should turn RED, whereas on success the border of fieldset should turn GREEN..

If any one of the input fails the feildset should show failure and success if all elements are correct..

```
<fieldset class="field">
<div class="visible column">
<div>
<?php echo $form->labelEx( $modelAddress, 'First Name'); ?>
 <?php echo $form->textField( $modelAddress, 'firstName'); ?> 
<div class="indicator">&nbsp;</div>
<?php echo $form->error( $modelAddress, 'firstName'); ?>
 </div>
</div>
</fieldset>

//My Script
<script>
$(document).ready(function()
{ $("input").each(function(){if ($(this).hasClass("error"))
 { $(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().addClass("fieldseterror");
}
}); 

</script>

//PHP
<?php
$form = $this->beginWidget( 'CActiveForm', array(
'id' => 'registration',
'enableAjaxValidation' => true,
'clientOptions'=>array(
'validateOnSubmit'=>true,
'afterValidate' => 'js:checkErrors'
    ),'htmlOptions' => array( 'class' => 'vertical inner custom_frm_styl')));
?>
```

Comment: If the indicator is activated,change the background to red

Comment: we have to set dynamicaally using find() and parent: but i cant able to fix..

Comment: Do you try use client form validation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jQuery.
Yii automatically changes non validating fields to have the class .error, so you can check if any of the form fields have the class .error to change whatever you want, eg (untested):

```
<script>
    $(function(){
        $('#user-form').submit(function(){
            $("#user-form input").each(function(){
            if ($(this).hasClass("error")){
                    ...
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use the [afterValidate](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveForm#clientOptions-detail) property of CActiveForm.

```
$myform = $this->beginWidget('CActiveForm',array('id'=>'invoice-form',
    'enableClientValidation'=>true,
'clientOptions'=>array(
        'validateOnSubmit'=>true,
        'afterValidate' => 'js:checkErrors'
    )
));

<script type="text/javascript"> 
    function checkErrors(form, data, hasError) {
        if(!hasError) {
            $('.field').addClass("fieldseterror");
            //$(form).submit();
            return true;
        }
        else {
            //return false;
                }

    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are just not accessing the correct `parent` element. Try:

```
$(this).parent().parent().parent().addClass("fieldseterror");
```

Also the best way to include jquery code in yii is to use [`CClientScript`'s `registerScript()`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CClientScript#registerScript-detail), so in your *create.php*, add:

```
Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScript('checkkk','
            $("input").each(function(){
                if ($(this).hasClass("error")) {
                    var parent_element = $(this).parent().parent().parent();
                    console.log(parent_element);
                    if (!parent_element.hasClass("fieldseterror"))
                        parent_element.addClass("fieldseterror");
                }
            });
'); // you can add this right before the call to renderPartial()
```

As you can see i have added a `console.log()` call to check for the matched parent element. Also it would be better to check if the fieldset already has the `fieldseterror` class or not, before adding it.

You don't need `validateOnSubmit` or `afterValidate`, for this.